# How to disable telerik validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, telerik, alert, raddatepicker

I m using Telerik raddatepicker. My Telerik version is 2009.

While setting fields, I'm getting range validation alert. but the field is what I enter. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztiqY.png)

```
   set_rangeMinDate: function(_8b) {
       if (this.RangeValidation.CompareDates(_8b, this.RangeMaxDate) > 0) {
            alert("RangeMinDate should be less than the RangeMaxDate value!");
            return;
       }
       ...
       ...
       ...
   }
```